# creating another partition out of the free space available in my existing primary partition

Tags: windows

Presently I have partitioned my hard disk into 3 primary partition and one extended in my Windows 8.1 machine. I have some free space in one of the primary partition (C:). I want to use that free space in creating another partition.
Is it possible? If yes, then someone please guide me the way!
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 you do the following steps, I think they can be done the same on Windows 8.1 if I remember correctly.

- Open Control Panel, use view small icon
- Find Administrative Tools, open it
- Open Computer Management
- Go to "Disk Management"
- Right click the disk you want to modify
- Shrink volume - it will say if and how much you can shrink

Or you could just in the start menu search for "Disk Management". 
(And do the last 2 steps.)